# Prevent PHP from printing error stack

Tags: php

If there is a fatal error - like unable to connect to database, then PHP is printing the error stack in the browser like follows -

```
mysql_pconnect() [<a href='function.mysql-pconnect'>function.mysql-pconnect</a>]: Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 111

#0 /var/www/platform/db/connection.php:12 mysql_pconnect('127.0.0.1','root','password')
#1 /var/www/platform/db/front_page.php:10 open_db_connection()
#2 /var/www/platform/services/front_page_services.php:7 find_top_courses()
#3 /var/www/platform/inc/main.php:75 get_top_courses()
#4 /var/www/index.php:198 F3::run()
```

How do I prevent this? `error_reporting` in `php.ini` has been set to `0` and `display_errors` to be Off.

Comment: And you restarted the server and verified those settings using `phpinfo()` ?

Comment: maybe there's somewhere an explicit debug_print_backtrace?

Comment: No I am sure there isn't any debug_print_backtrace anywhere

Comment: nowhere, and nowhere some error handler installed?

Comment: Thankyou. I found the problem. It was an error handler in the framework code - pretty lame. Can you make your comment an answer so that I can mark it as correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure no script is enabling `display_errors` during run-time or through `.htaccess`.

If that still doesn't work, be sure you're modifying the right `php.ini`, and restarting Apache/IIS/nginx after any changes are made. If that still fails, load up a `phpinfo()` and ensure the changes are taking.

Also, be sure to turn `html_errors` off too. Just in case a script sneaks by that changes your error_reporting, and it shows your stack trace to the public.

Comment: `html_errors` only controls if the error message should contain HTML with links or not. It has nothing to do with wether or not the errors show up.

Comment: @Radu Correct, but having it on in a production environment is not good idea, in my opinion at least. I will edit my comment to reflect that rather than solving the actual issue.

Comment: Having the errors show up *in the first place* in a production environment is not a good idea. They should be logged, with or without HTML, so this is a non-issue.

Comment: @Radu Agreed. But there's always the off-chance that someone turned something on to debug, and forgot to change it back the way it was. It's merely far down in safety net, where X/Y needs to happen first. Again, this is based on my experience with working with multiple teams, and just my opinion.

Comment: My phphinfo() is showing that display_errors and html_errors are Off but I am still getting the error stack. Does that mean that it is being reset in some script?

Comment: If you add this at the top of your script, what do you get? `echo ini_get('display_errors');` If you get 1, you may want to try this: `ini_set('display_errors', 0)` Also if you're on Linux/Unix, I would check for a `.htaccess` file to ensure there's not a PHP flag hiding there that's toggling it.

Comment: I have a .htaccess file - how do I verify whether there is any flag which is toggling the flag?

Comment: Also surpisingly, ini_get('display_erros') in the file connection.php returns 0. This is the file where the database connection is made (details in question).

Answer (score 1):

either you're editing the wrong php.ini, or the settings were turned back on somewhere else(.htaccess file, a user level php.ini, or in the script at runtime). see phpinfo() to help you find the php.ini file, edit it, and then reboot.

you only need to turn display_errors off.

Answer (score -2):

You can use the "@" before the function that raise the error.

the "@" will silent any php error your function could raise.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php

Comment: While this would work, it's not a good idea, since you'd have to put it in front of every function.

Comment: This is basically sweeping the problem under the carpet.  Errors occur because something is wrong, it's much better to fix the root cause of the error than to ignore it.

Comment: Yes, i do agree, but the question was about Preventing PHP from printing error stack, not about finding a solution for the problem.

Comment: the answer is formally correct; making the error quiet does not mean to avoid handling it: I suppose the user check for the failure of the function, doesn't he? the answer does not help in identifying the reason why the error appears while the user thinks it shouldn't... but there are not too much clues, so other answers are simply "arguing" what could be wrong: common sense and bets, while this is an actual solution, if the problem were to be solved quickly. +1 just to compensate undeserved -1